# Magento theme not displaying on front-end after install

Tags: configuration, theme, theme-fallback

I'm fairly new to Magento. I have successfully installed Magento, sourced a theme I like and followed the install instructions.

When the theme is installed and theme name is entered into: System > Config > Design > Default: 'Theme Name'

It makes no changes to my website.

I have looked around the web for answers and this had led me to try refreshing the cache.

From what i've read, it sounds like the theme I have installed is not being found my Magento and is falling back to the default theme, but I can't seem to find a fix.

I'm not sure if i'm meant to post website details here, but the website is:[enter link description here](http://www.thriffft.com)

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks

[image]

Comment: can you please show me your back end theme configuration

Comment: did you mention package name(if you use custom package)

Comment: I don't believe im using a custom package no. Image has been added to question. I hope this is what you were asking for?

Comment: just add template, layout and skin also mention your theme name

Comment: I have added the theme name to template, layout & skin. Still no changes. The theme i'm working with is: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/kartparadigm-elegance-theme.html

Comment: clear your cache and then check

Comment: Still no cigar.. I did think it could be to do with the name 'Kartparadigm' im using in the fields. I've also tried Kartparadigm_theme (as seen in the key) but this doesn't work either.

Comment: what is the name of theme folder and package folder

Comment: It's all working now, my package name was incorrect and has been fixed. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fill your theme name into Template , Layout and skin

Make sure your Theme name and Package name

After that clear cache

Answer (score 0):

First you should check default store configuration
Copy all templates/layout file to correct package
Clean cache store